# Plotting fixed slice pie chart with value range from -1 to 1

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset like

```
Name test1 test2 test3 
John   1     0    -1
```

I am trying to plot a pie chart which shows 3 tests with different color based on the values such as red color for -1, blue color for zero, green color for +1.

For more clarifications, I was trying to show a pie chart to show the sentiment of test takers, over here which is John. Positive sentiment is represented here with 1, neutral with 0 and negative sentiment with -1. So the pie chart will have 3 fixed slice for each test(33.33 %area each). Each area can be identified with unique color such as, in our case for John, test1 area is green, test2 area is blue and test3 area is red.

Thank you.

Comment: The numbers give the relative areas of the slices. There are no *negative areas*, so your data will throw an error. If you add 2 to all, they will become `c(3, 2, 1)` and the ex -1 will have an area 3 times smaller than the ex 1 but if you add 1e9 to all, the areas will be the same. Exactly what do you want to plot?

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of ways to make a pie chart, but we don't know what you're trying to do

Comment: Thank you, Rui Barradas. You are correct if we add 2 to all values, it will omit the negative value. But, I was trying to show a pie chart to show the sentiment of test takers, over here which is John. Positive sentiment is represented here with 1, neutral with 0 and negative sentiment with -1. So the pie chart will have 3 fixed slice for each test(33.33 %area each). Each area can be identified with unique color such as, in our case for John, test1 area is green, test2 area is blue and test3 area is red.

Comment: Then the best way is a barplot. If the data set is named `df1` see if the following does it: `barplot(unlist(df1[1, -1]), col = c("green", "blue", "red"))`. Also, I only answered to your comment now because I didn't know about it. To ping a mailbox, put an at sign, @, right before the user's name.